# Solution via method of characteristics and on the uniqueness in non-linear first order Cauchy Problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I came across a multiple select question:

Q. If $u(x, y)$ satisfy the PDE $$u_x u_y=x y,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$

$ u=x$, along $y=0$. Then, $u(x, y)$ can be of the form

(a) $x^2\left(y^2+1\right)$

(b) $x^2 y^2$

(c) $x^2\left(y^2-1\right)$

(d) $x\sqrt{y^2+1}$

Despite of the easy selection (d), let me try to solve it by method of characteristics. Consider the characteristic system

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=q(t)=u_y(t), $$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=p(t)=u_x(t),$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=2p(t)q(t),$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=y(t),$$
$$\frac{dq}{dt}=x(t),$$
to get, $$x(t)=Ae^t+Be^{-t},$$
$$ y(t)=Ce^t+De^{-t},$$
$$u(t)=(ACe^{2t}-BDe^{-2t})+(AD+BC)t+E,$$
$p(t)=Ce^t-De^{-t},$ and $q(t)=Ae^t-Be^{-t}., $ where $A,B,C,D,E,F$ and $G$ are arbitrary constants.

Now, apply the initial curve (described by $x(s,0)=s,~y(s,0)=0,~u(s,0)=x(s,0)=s$) to obtain,

$$A+B=s,$$
$$C+D=0,$$
$$AC-BD+E=s,$$ and I hope, taking $p(s,0)=u_x(s,0)=1$ and $q(s,0)=0$ (from $(*)$) is the way to say,
$$C-D=1,~\text{and},$$
$$A-B=0.$$
Therefore, we have $A=B=E=s/2,~C=-D=1/2$. But, I am unable to proceed now.

Could you please point out any errors in the deduction so far and suggest the next step to reach a possibly unique solution (I am hesitant about uniqueness in non-linear Cauchy problems as well!) that is provided in option (d)? I would be grateful for your any sort of help.

Comment: Ya...exactly, I have corrected it, thank you, now my concern is about $A,B$ and $E$.

Comment: That's nice, any idea about the uniqueness of solution in non-linear Cauchy problems? I think the uniqueness has not yet been established. right?